# How to differentiate the function $f(x) = [ \frac{a+x}{b+x}]^{a+b+2x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It has been given that, $$f(x) = \Big[ \frac{a+x}{b+x}\Big]^{a+b+2x}$$

How to prove , $$f'(0) = 2\ln  \frac{a}{b}+ \frac{b^2-a^2}{ab}\Big[\frac{a}{b}\Big]^{a+b}$$

Do I have to take the logarithm of both sides of the first equation?

Comment: f is composition of differencaible funtions then you can apply the chain rule

Comment: can you do some lines so i can follow you?

Comment: Yes, you can take $\log$ of both sides and then differentiate. I believe this is how this type of derivative is usually taught in high school, though I'm not completely sure why, as the chain rule is perfectly serviceable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write the expression:

$$f(x) = \left( \dfrac{a+x}{b+x}\right)^{a+b+2x}$$

as:

$$\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(\dfrac{a+x}{b+x}\right)^{a+b+2x}\right)\right) = \exp\left((a+b+2x)\ln\left(\dfrac{a+x}{b+x}\right)\right)$$

We now have the form:

$$\dfrac {d}{du} e^u = e^u \dfrac{du}{dx}$$

After you find the derivative, rewrite the expression without the exponential and then evaluate it at zero to arrive at your result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking logarithm of both sides is not necessary. Just use a simple identity $$f=e^{\ln f}$$
For $f$ being a power: $f=B^E$ that makes $$f=e^{\ln(B^E)}=e^{E\ln B}$$ then by the chain rule $$f' = e^{E\ln B}\cdot (E\ln B)'=e^{\ln f}\cdot(E'\ln B + E(\ln B)')$$ $$=f\cdot(E'\ln B + \tfrac EB\,B')$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:-**

$y=\left(\dfrac{a+x}{b+x}\right)^{a+b+2x} \implies \ln y=(a+b+2x)\ln (a+x)-(a+b+2x)\ln (b+x)$